# Default document ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

My login.aspx is my default document, so now when a user goes on my website they'll be on login.aspx however from URL it won't show that, instead it will show:

http://localhost:52294/

Rather than:

http://localhost:52294/login.aspx

Now when a user logs out they are redirected to the login.aspx, when they're redirected the URL is this

http://localhost:52294/login.aspx

How would I make it so when they're redirected it just shows http://localhost:52294/ rather than the additional "login.aspx" ?

Would it also be possible to redirect the user to the site root rather than specifying the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect to "/".  This answers both your questions.

Comment: So simple.. Thank you